# Creating custom classes for list storage

Tags: oop

When is it acceptable to do this. For example, I find myself sometimes needing to create, say, a form of tuple or something that has a key

so like a

```
String -> (myObj1, myObj2, myObj3)
```

I end up making a class to hold the `myObj1 -> 3` but as you can see this class has limited fields so it seems like its a waste of a class as such.

Should I not worry about that or is it bad design to create classes for list storage purposes?

Comment: Why don't you use lists (= vector, array) and dictionaries (= map, hash)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how *complicated* the list objects are. Most languages/frameworks have build in classes for `tuples`, `pairs`, `key->value pairs`, `points`, `associative arrays` and similar forms. If your objects are a little more *complicated* and can't find anything that fits your needs use a custom class. I don't see any problems here.

There are various options:
C# KeyValue: `IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`
C# Dictionaty: `Dictionary<string, string>)`
Java: `Map<String, String>`
Php associative arrays: `$myVal = $myArray['$myKey']`